# Kingfisher: Ambiguous use of 'setBackgroundImage(with:for:placeholder:options:progressBlock:completionHandler:)'

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I've been trying to use Kingfisher to set the background image of a button, but I'm getting a swift compiler error:

> Ambiguous use of
>   'setBackgroundImage(with:for:placeholder:options:progressBlock:completionHandler:)'

What about this expression is ambiguous? I looked at the KF documentation and I think this is how you call it.

```
var options: KingfisherOptionsInfo = []
options.append(.forceRefresh)
button.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: picture), for: .normal, placeholder: nil, options: options, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: which kingfisher  & swift versions ?

Comment: Swift 4.2, kingfisher 5.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is because you need to handle the `completionHandler` instead of passing `nil`.  Try below code:

```
button.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: picture), for: .normal, placeholder: nil, options: options, progressBlock: nil) { result in
    // result is either a .success(RetrieveImageResult) or a .failure(KingfisherError)
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
        // The image was set to image view:
        print(value.image)

        // From where the image was retrieved:
        // - .none - Just downloaded.
        // - .memory - Got from memory cache.
        // - .disk - Got from disk cache.
        print(value.cacheType)

        // The source object which contains information like `url`.
        print(value.source)

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error) // The error happens
    }
}
```

Comment: we can remove that parameter which we have to pass nil wen function call, then error will go away - worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it by just removing the nil parameters in the function call.

```
imgBanner.kf.setImage(with: url , placeholder:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "landscape.png"), options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

with

```
 imgBanner.kf.setImage(with: url , placeholder:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "landscape.png"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**For swift 5**

replace your line with this.

```
videoImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: nil, options: [.transition(.fade(0)), .processor(p)], progressBlock: nil) { (result) in
                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by stripping the function call of unused parameters (where we pass `nil`) and importing Kingfisher.

**Step 1**. `import Kingfisher`

**Step 2**. `button.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: urlString), for: .normal, options: options)`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me very basic fix, Use `URL(string: url)` instead of just string `url` Xcode required type-specific

```
cell.imgView.kf.setImage(
            with: URL(string: url),
            placeholder: UIImage(named: "dummyaadhar"),
            options: [
                .processor(processor),
                .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
                .transition(.fade(1)),
                .cacheOriginalImage
            ])
```